# Rails delete link nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm writing a simple todo app which has projects and projects has many tasks.  I want to be able to delete a task within a project.  But when I try to link_to a delete method I get undefined method 'task_path'.

view code

```
<ul>
  <% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
    <li><%= task.name %></li> <%= link_to "delete", task, :method  => :delete %></br>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

tasks controller

```
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    redirect_to @project, :notice => "Task Deleted"
  end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :projects do
    resources :tasks
  end
```

Update:
So I have delete working.  But now as I'm iterating through each task, there's an extra delete link which routes to http://todoapp.dev/projects/9/tasks and gives No route matches [DELETE] "/projects/9/tasks"  Why is the extra delete link in there?

```
 <% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
    <%= task.name %> <%= link_to "delete", [@project, task], :method  => :delete %>
  <% end %>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look to [Rails Guide: Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: It probably needs the project id, could you post what you get after running `rake routes` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<%= link_to "delete", [@project, task], :method  => :delete %>
```

and let me know

Comment: This worked for me.  Looks like I had to pass the @project variable to get the path to the task.  Thanks!

Comment: There's an extra delete listed in my updated question above.  Not sure why that's there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wha's `<%= debug @project.tasks %>` output?

Comment: ---
- !ruby/object:Task
  attributes:
    id: 
    name: 
    created_at: 
    updated_at: 
    project_id: 9
    completed: false

Answer (score 1):

Running `rake routes` you will see that the delete is mapped to project_task.

You may use

```
<ul>
  <% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
    <li><%= task.name %></li> <%= link_to "delete", project_task_path(@project, task), :method  => :delete %></br>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: This makes sense.  But when I try to do this and delete a task I get the following.  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tasks", :project_id=>#<Project id: 9, name: "House Items", created_at: "2013-04-26 12:18:19", updated_at: "2013-04-26 12:18:19">, :id=>#<Task id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, project_id: 9, completed: false>}

Comment: Hmmm.. This means that method wasn't set correctly to :delete so it did a normal get request. By the way, in your comment, how are you gonna delete a task if it's id is nil???

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  I'm not sure why it would show up as nil.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have tasks in your project that are not yet saved.

Comment: When I get in the console and do a Task.all I return [] or Task.count I get a count of 0.

Comment: So you have no tasks. You shouldn't allow delete action on non persistent objects.

Comment: Yep, so now to get rid of the delete link if there are no tasks?  Usually if I include this in a block the link will only show up if there's a task.  How to get rid of this?  I'm not following.