# Understanding link_to for deleting nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm learning ruby and rails too. I understood how the link_to and deleting items worked with a single resource.

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And this works since it uses the article_path and uses rails magic where it takes takes article.id although article was passed in and there was a route article with DELETE and it needed the `:id`

```
Prefix   Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
article  GET    /articles/:id(.:format)  articles#show
         DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)  articles#destroy
```

---

However after nesting a resource inside it say, comments

To delete a comment it becomes

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Here are the (relevant) routes for the nested resource (note :format is ommitted)

```
Prefix          Verb    URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
article_comment GET     /articles/:article_id/comments/:id comments#show
                DELETE  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id comments#destroy
```

Controller code

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
```

View code

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong> <%= comment.username %> </strong>: <%= comment.body %>
    <!-- link_to goes here -->
  </p>
<% end %>
```

---

## Q1)

Firstly, is there another syntax for deleting a comment i.e another way of doing `[comment.article, comment]` in the structure of `article_comment_path(comment)` (like with non-nested resources in the first code block).

## Q2)

What does `[comment.article, comment]` mean/do and how does it translate to the correct route with

`DELETE  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id comments#destroy`

(Rails has a lot of syntactic sugar (I come from a Java background) so as I code I'm trying not to use syntactic sugar until I fully understand it.)

---

[This code is all from section 5.13 (non nested resources)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-articles) and [section 8 (nested resources)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-comments) of 
[guides.rubyonrails.org.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Answer (score 0):

For Q1) I found an answer which was

The wanted alternative syntax is

`article_comment_path(@article.id, comment.id)`

So overall

`<%= link_to 'Destroy comment', article_comment_path(@article.id, comment.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>`
[This answer was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16236552/7159163)

And the reason why you need the id for the article and the comment is that they are required due to the way the DELETE route is structured. `@article.id` is needed for `articles/:article_id/` and`comment.id` is needed for `comments/:id`

I would also like to add `article_comment_path(@article.id, comment.id)` in the link_to can be replaced with `[@article, comment]`. However if using this array input approach you cannot specify specifically the id, the whole object must be passed. So you **cannot do** `[@article.id, comment.id]` (Although I  somewhat understand this array syntax with link_to im yet to get how q2 works).